# How to import a .owl file and ask query in Pyhon?

Tags: python, owl, ontology, semantic-web

I have a .owl file which I have developed using Protege software. My question is what to do next? How to query the ontology in Python? How to import the .owl file ? I wanted some direction. Please help me !

Comment: "what to do next" is a weird question ... why did you create the ontology at all if you don't know what to do with it? For Python you should use the search engine of your choice and find tools like `owlready´, ´rdflib´, etc.

Comment: @UninformedUser, what to do next means like how to implement it?  suppose I am getting some data from the sensors and the data has to get in through the ontology and if I ask a query the ontology should answer. How to start these things in Python?